# Hover Effect using CSS and Javascript/Prototype

Tags: javascript, html, css, prototypejs

I have a 4x4 matrix of tiles. Each tile is basically a `div`. Now, I want to do the following:

- When the mouse pointer is on a particular tile, I have to check perform a check on that tile(using position and stuff, which i have already done). If the tile meets the requirements, then it should have a hover effect.

Note: that the tiles keep changing positions, so at one moment the given tile must have the hover effect, but after rearrangement, it may not have it. And the rearrangement is not complete, ie i dont not reset the whole matrix. It involves only shifting a couple of tiles.

I need to implement this using css class and javascript(prototype, not jquery). I set a hover style for class `hoverTile`. I added a mouseover to each tile, such that whenever the user's mouse is over a tile, my function is called, which sets the class for the html div element using `setAttribute`.
Here is a summary:

```
Before:
<div> ... </div>

After:
<div class="hoverTile"> ... </div>
```

Style:

```
.hoverTile: hover{
    text-color: red;
}
```

This does not seem to work, even though the class name appears when i inspect the html page. What is the mistake here?

Comment: can we see a demo? it's hard to visualize without one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the demo I set up for you [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9MejY/)

2 issues:

1) your seudo-selector (`:hover`) shouldn't have a space after the colon (`:`).

2) `text-color` should just be `color`

Comment: Thanks! one more question. How do you change the border color? I tried using border-color: red but it does not work :/

Comment: just put the border color with the rest of the border styles you want to use (e.g., `border: 5px solid #ff0000;`). I'm sorry for taking so long to see your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Micron and Igo probably answered your question although i'd like to add that you could achieve the same effect by adding 

`div:hover { color: red;
}`

(you might not need the hoverTile class).

As for the border color

`border-color:red;` should work. [[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-color.asp)] So  
`.hoverTile { border: 5px solid #ff0000; }` in your scheme.

Comment: (RE: border-color; I'm guessing he forgot to add a border width and border style.)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should be

```
.hoverTile:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

not `text-color` (which is not a CSS property). Hope that fixes it.

**EDIT:** Also, if I understand correctly, you are adding `hoverTile` class on mouseover? In that case, you wouldn't need the `:hover` pseudo-class in your CSS at all. Make sure to remove the `hoverTile` class on mouseout though.